I'm trying to upload a dxf file into a Laravel 11x project with validations, but it only work when it has no validation on it?
I created a upload project in Laravel 11x. I'm trying to upload a dxf file and add validations to only accept that file but it only passes when there is no validations on it.
I tried different mime types given through searching, but none of them are working.
$request->validate([
'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
    'file' => [
        'required',
        'file',
        'max:2048',
        'mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,pdf,dxf'
    ],
]);

$file = $request->file('file');
$filename = time() . '_' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
$path = $file->storeAs('uploads', $filename, 'public');

$extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$mimeType = $file->getMimeType();
Log::info("File extension: {$extension}");
Log::info("File mime type: {$mimeType}");

I have tried this above and only the images (jpeg, png) are uploading but not the dxf file. When I do it like this, then it works.
$file = $request->file('file');
$filename = time() . '_' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
$path = $file->storeAs('uploads', $filename, 'public');

// Optionally log file details for debugging
$extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
$mimeType = $file->getMimeType();
Log::info("File extension: {$extension}");
Log::info("File mime type: {$mimeType}");

Product::create([
    'name' => $request->name,
    'img' => $filename,
    'user_id' => Auth::id(),
]);

return back()->with('success', 'Product added successfully!');


Add the mime type logging before the validation, and see what it is compared to your validation.

Are you sure that it's failed according to the mime type validation? Maybe the size attribute?
